# How to perform animation before prepareForSegue is called and dismiss when it's finished?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, uistoryboardsegue, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I want to achieve this but non of my approaches work:

**1. user taps "DoneButton" to go to the next view controller.**

**2. waiting animation shows up before prepareForSegue starts it's code.**

**3. Stop/dismiss the waiting animation once prepareForSegue wants to load the next view controller.**

**My problem:**
The method `[self startWaitingAnimation];` does get called but I guess the operation inside prepareForSegue blocks the mainThread, hence I only see the animation just when prepareForSegue is finished. but I want the animation to show up first and then run the code inside the prepareForSegue and once the next View controller is ready, dismiss the animation.

**Ways I tried to do it**,

1. Using semaphore queues so it would dismiss the animation after the code inside prepareForSegue finished. (didn't work)
2. Using dispatch_group.

dispatch_queue_t queue =                      dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

```
- (void)goToNextVC{
       dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
             [self startWaitingAnimation];
       });
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filtersAndEdits" sender:self];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{          
       if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"filtersAndEdits"]) {
            dispatch_group_async(_group, _queue, ^{

               AFBlurSegue *blurSegue = (AFBlurSegue *)segue;
               blurSegue.blurRadius = 20;
               blurSegue.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:1/255 blue:0/255 alpha:0.1];
               blurSegue.saturationDeltaFactor = 0.5;

              //Transferring Image Data to FilterAndEdits
              NSMutableArray*finalP =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_drawableView.modifiablePointsArray];

              FiltersAndEdits *FVC = [segue destinationViewController];
              [FVC getFinalPointsArray:finalP];
              [FVC getBgImage: self.image];
              FVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

           });

           dispatch_group_notify(_group, _queue, ^{
              [self stopWaitingAnimation];
           });
    }else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"HomeVC"]){
           HomeVC*homeVC = [HomeVC new];
           homeVC=segue.destinationViewController;
           [homeVC setShouldRemoveBlackScreen:YES];
           [homeVC removeBlackTempScreen];
           [self.waitingActivity stopAnimating];
    }            
}`
```

3.Using NSOperationQueues and NSOperation

```
     NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
     queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount =1;



- (void)goToNextVC{
        self.operationA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
           [self startWaitingAnimation];
        }];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        self.operationB = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

            AFBlurSegue *blurSegue = (AFBlurSegue *)segue;
            blurSegue.blurRadius = 20;
            blurSegue.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:1/255 blue:0/255 alpha:0.1];
            blurSegue.saturationDeltaFactor = 0.5;

            //Transferring Image Data to FilterAndEdits
            NSMutableArray*finalP =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_drawableView.modifiablePointsArray];

            FiltersAndEdits *FVC = [segue destinationViewController];
            [FVC getFinalPointsArray:finalP];
            [FVC getBgImage: self.image];
            FVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        }];

        self.operationC = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self stopWaitingAnimation];
        }];

        [operationB addDependency:operationA]; 
        [operationC addDependency:operationB];
        [self.queue addOperation:self.operationA];
        [self.queue addOperation:operationB];
        [self.queue addOperation:operationB];
}
```

What should I do? Should I use completion handler inside prepareForSegue method? what is the right approach? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why won’t you use UIView.animateWithDuration with completion handler. Inside you put the startanimating, duration 0.4. In completion block you add the performSegue.

Comment: Because I'm using DGActivityIndicatorView, it's not an animation with animateWithDuration

Comment: https://github.com/gontovnik/DGActivityIndicatorView

Comment: Have you tried using dispatch_group_wait?

Comment: the problem is that prepareForSegue doesnt even let the animation to show up! it blocks the mainThread in all cases! and nope I havnt tried that :(

Comment: Have you tried      dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t when, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block) . . . . . . Start animation than call the Dispatch_after function and pass the [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filtersAndEdits" sender:self]; in block.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dispatch_after function of Dispatch library I believe it will solve your problem:

```
- (void)goToNextVC{
 //Start the animation
 dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("backgroundQueue", 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    [self startWaitingAnimation];
});
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int)(700 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filtersAndEdits" sender:self];
    });
});

}
```

Comment: As I've mentioned above, It doesn't always guarantee that animation will show up first, it mostly works but not always. But thank you so much.

Comment: You can submit both task (animation and navigation call) to a serial queue to make sure that animation will show up first. as i edited the Answer

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Thanks to @NisarAhmad it **mostly** works but not always.

It sometimes still doesn't let the animation to run. It doesn't guarantee to let the animation to show up always before executing the block.

```
- (void)goToNextVC{
     //Start the animation
     [self startWaitingAnimation];

     //Showing animation for 0.7 second.
     dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int)(700 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filtersAndEdits" sender:self];
     });
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"filtersAndEdits"]) {
            //Transferring Image Data to FilterAndEdits
            NSMutableArray*finalP =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_drawableView.modifiablePointsArray];
            FiltersAndEdits *FVC = [segue destinationViewController];
            [FVC getFinalPointsArray:finalP];
            [FVC getBgImage: self.image];
            FVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            AFBlurSegue *blurSegue = (AFBlurSegue *)segue;
            blurSegue.blurRadius = 20;
            blurSegue.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:1/255 blue:0/255 alpha:0.1];
            blurSegue.saturationDeltaFactor = 0.5;

            //Stop the animation.
            [self stopWaitingAnimation];

        }else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"HomeVC"]){
            //Other codes related to previous VC
        }
}
```